# Calendar library supporting holidays

Tags: php, javascript, calendar

Are there any existing library that support holidays (e.g. Christmas) highlight in the calendar itself?

Google Calendar is fine, but I just want to use the library to display the calendar, I don't actually needed to create the events.

Any idea?

Comment: You should be a little more clear about what you mean by "calendar".  Are we talking about a full-blown calendar application?  A "date picker" widget?  A view-only schedule display?  There are *lots* of user interface components that can loosely be called "calendars."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with you saying *holidays* is that you are assuming a certain country / geographical / religious affiliation.

What you should really be looking for is a way to mark certain dates with *something*, as ultimately that is what you need.  Holidays mean nothing other than days marked off or showing different from another.  Google does this by utilizing feeds (which you could use).

Mozilla keeps a list of holidays as well:
http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/holidays.html

You will have to apply the list to your chosen calendar (most support day / date changes, and you would loop through your holiday list and add those days / mark as special).

Here is an example of **jQuery Datepicker** with *Bank Holidays*:
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/renderCalendarBankHolidays.html

Hope that gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

Rather late in posting an answer, but as the current maintainer of the relevant PEAR Packages, I would suggest that you utilise [the Date Holidays suite of components from PEAR](https://pear.php.net/package/Date_Holidays). There are drivers for most countries: Australia, USA, UK, Germany, Russia and others.