# PHP how to check if a day was a holiday (in a specified country)?

Tags: php

Is there some function that would tell me if a date was a holiday in a certain country?

I know this is probably futile question as it would be difficult to have a function like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calendar library supporting holidays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539942/calendar-library-supporting-holidays)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_holidays_by_country , You could add them all to your custom made function! :-)

Comment: You'd have to have a database of sorts (like these guys e.g.: http://www.bank-holidays.com/publicholidays_2011_63.htm ), containing all the holidays first, before you can start tackle this issue. PHP doesn't come with anything so specialized to my knowledge.

Comment: i'd prefer built-in php function `get_lottery_winning_number()` though ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think you are going to have to roll your own. And even if there is already a lib that does this for you, you are going to have to be careful - the definition of holiday will vary, even for a given country. (E.g does a religious holiday mean the banks are shut?). I.e what constitutes a holiday is likely to be application dependent. Take a look at this wikipedia page for lists of national holidays: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_holidays_by_country

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in function for this, but you might be able to roll-your-own using the holiday script at [AbleDesign](http://abledesign.com/programs/holiday_code.php) as the base

Comment: This is truly a great reference.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rather late in posting an answer, but as the current maintainer of the relevant PEAR Packages, I would suggest that you utilise [the Date Holidays suite of components from PEAR](https://pear.php.net/package/Date_Holidays). There are drivers for most countries: Australia, USA, UK, Germany, Russia and others.